# How to parametrize an algorithm with a custom non-pure swap-function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, stl, overload-resolution

I want to apply an algorithm from `<algorithms>` on ranges of elements, containing in one container, defined by iterator pairs, containing into another one. To do this I need a `swap` function with state: just pointer to the container with elements to be able to make `swap`s synchronously in both containers.

This is my incomplete attempt:

```
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

inline
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const std::pair< int, int > & p)
{   
    return out << '{' << p.first << ", " << p.second << '}';
}   

int main()
{   
    using L = std::list< std::pair< int, int > >;
    using I = typename L::const_iterator;
    using P = std::pair< I, I >;
    using R = std::vector< P >;
    L values;
    R ranges;
    auto l = std::cbegin(values);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        l = values.emplace(std::cend(values), i, 0); 
        auto & p = ranges.emplace_back(l, l); 
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            p.second = values.emplace(std::cend(values), i, j); 
        }   
    }   
    const auto swap = [&values] (P & l, P & r)
    {   
        auto ll = std::next(l.second);
        auto rr = std::next(r.second);
        if (ll == r.first) {
            values.splice(rr, values, l.first, ll);
        } else if (rr == l.first) {
            values.splice(ll, values, r.first, rr);
        } else {
            L temp;
            temp.splice(std::cend(temp), values, l.first, ll);
            values.splice(ll, values, r.first, rr);
            values.splice(rr, std::move(temp));
        }   
        std::swap(l, r); 
    };  
    for (const auto & p : values) {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }   
    std::cout << "-----" << std::endl;
    std::shuffle(std::begin(ranges), std::end(ranges), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}); // just an example, it can be any algo, say std::sort w/ custom comparator
    for (const auto & p : values) {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For sure the `swap` function object from the above code cannot "participate in overload resolution" (it is oxymoron in the current context because of many reasons, please, do not focus on this).

What I can to do is to define a tagged version of iterator pair in an namespace scope (global (either named or anonymous one, not matters much)) like this `using P = struct { std::pair< I, I > p };` and overloading of the free function `void swap(P & l, P & r);` with the body of the lambda from the code above. Also I surely should to make `values` a global variable. It leads to hindering of the usefulness of the approach from the code above.

Is there a way to pass a stateful `swap` function to the algorithms from `<algorithm>` in a more generic way, then described above?

I read [the article](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/) and [draft](http://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4381.html) about customization points of Eric Niebler. But his approach imply modification of the STL. Either way even if it would be the point his approach cannot allow me to pass stateful overloadings from the function scope, I think, isn't it?

Comment: Rather than `ranges` being a container of `std::pair<I, I>`, why not of `struct { I first; I second; L & list; }`?

Comment: As an aside, all your `p.second`s are elements of L of the form `i, i`. Do you intend that?

Comment: @Caleth It is one of thinkable solutions, but it leads to extra data duplication.

Comment: @Caleth `std::pair< int, int >` elements are just for example. `first` is just a number of a range here and the `second` is an unique value within the range. It is intended for ease of visual distinction. All ranges are of different lengths.

Comment: For `struct { I first; I second; L * list = {}; }` one also need to overload move constructor and move assignment operator to interoperate w/ `std::swap` properly.

Comment: Not really, because all the `list`s are the same `L`

Comment: @Caleth But how can `values` be affected by just swapping of another values of almost POD type in another container?

Answer (score 1):

You can just include `values` in your range object.

```
struct Range { I first; I second; L & list; }

void swap(Range & l, Range & r)
{
    assert(std::addressof(l.list) == std::addressof(r.list));
    using std::swap;

    auto ll = std::next(l.second);
    auto rr = std::next(r.second);
    if (ll == r.first) {
        l.list.splice(rr, l.list, l.first, ll);
    } else if (rr == l.first) {
        l.list.splice(ll, l.list, r.first, rr);
    } else {
        L temp;
        temp.splice(std::cend(temp), l.list, l.first, ll);
        l.list.splice(ll, l.list, r.first, rr);
        l.list.splice(rr, std::move(temp));
    }   
    swap(l.first, r.first); 
    swap(l.second, r.second); 
}
```

Comment: You meant defining the free function. I like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find a better way (if compare with ones based on `swap` function overloading) to implement desired: two-pass way to apply changes. It gives just linear overhead, instead of the algorithm of interest's complexity.

```
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cassert>

inline
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const std::pair< int, int > & p)
{
    return out << '{' << p.first << ", " << p.second << '}';
}

int main()
{
    using L = std::list< std::pair< int, int > >;
    using I = typename L::const_iterator;
    using P = std::pair< I, I >;
    using R = std::vector< P >;
    L values;
    R ranges;
    auto l = std::cbegin(values);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        l = values.emplace(std::cend(values), i, 0);
        auto & p = ranges.emplace_back(l, l);
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            p.second = values.emplace(std::cend(values), i, j);
        }
    }
    for (const auto & p : values) {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "-----" << std::endl;
    std::shuffle(std::begin(ranges), std::end(ranges), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    l = std::cbegin(values);
    for (const auto & range : ranges) {
        auto r = std::next(range.second);
        if (l != range.first) {
            values.splice(l, values, range.first, r);
        }
        l = r;
    }
    assert(l == std::cend(values));
    for (const auto & p : values) {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Don't think it can be applicable to containers with somehow stricter iterators invalidation rules.